# removing white pixels (alpha channel) in a png

Tags: android, png

I have an ImageView that uses a png of a coin.  the png is square and everything outside of the round coin is showing as white in stead of clear.  How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the corner are not transparent in you png file.

You need to make them transparent beforehand using your favorite image editor, or you can use an online service [Here](http://www.lunapic.com/editor/?action=transparent)